# PHP walk through recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got the following recursive function that loops through nested array and replicates a json like format, I cannot use json_encode just incase anyone thinks why I don't just use json_encode. The function works well so far, however From each section, I need to be able to remove the last comma and also, ideally I want to create the correct indentation to make it look pretty.

Any ideas how I can do this? Thanks

```
function walk_array($array) {
  foreach($array as $idx => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
    echo '"'.$idx.'":{<br>  ';
     walk_array($val);
    echo "},<br>";
    } else {
    echo '"'.$idx.'":"'.$val.'",<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

*** UPDATE - Sample Array to use ***

```
$array = array
  ( 'brands' => array
    (
      'codes' => array('b' => "Apple", 'c' => 21, 'd' => 18),
      'items' => array('b' => "Google", 'c' => 22, 'd' => 19),
      'stock' => array('b' => "Samsung", 'c' => 23, 'd' => array('b' => "Samsung", 'c' => 23, 'd' => 20))
    )
  );
```

Needs to look a bit like this:

```
"brands":{

    "codes":{
        "b":"Apple",
        "c":"21",
        "d":"18"
    }

}
```

Comment: Next question is __why__ you cannot use `json_encode`?

Comment: Not sure why `json_encode()` is restricted.. If you are able to figure out till here, then you can probably answer your own questions.

Comment: can you put an example of your array and what you need as output ?

Comment: @MoxGeek i've added sample array

Comment: what about output ?

Comment: @MoxGeek added sample output too of just one level of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a check for the last index

```
function walk_array($array) {
  $lastIndex = count($array);
  $i = 0;
  foreach($array as $idx => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
    echo '"'.$idx.'":{<br>  ';
     walk_array($val);
    if(++$i == $lastIndex )
     echo "}<br>";
    else
     echo "},<br>";
    } else {
   if(++$i == $lastIndex )
    echo '"'.$idx.'":"'.$val.'"<br>';    
   else
    echo '"'.$idx.'":"'.$val.'",<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It Doesn't seem to work. It only removes only the last comma in the entire loop. I've  updated with a sample array

Comment: that works now, any ideas how i can make the indentation work so that the levels and sub levels are all correctly indented to look pretty?

Comment: I guess you could use something like  echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5); and iterates the number based on levels. and a lot of hacky checks. I would try to figure that json_encode issue out though. you might have more complex arrays and shouldn't have to write algorithms for them too.

Answer (score 0):

here is a statements :

```
$array = array
  ( 'brands' => array
    (
      'codes' => array('b' => "Apple", 'c' => 21, 'd' => 18),
      'items' => array('b' => "Google", 'c' => 22, 'd' => 19),
      'stock' => array('b' => "Samsung", 'c' => 23, 'd' => array('b' => "Samsung", 'c' => 23, 'd' => 20))
    )
  );

  function walk_array($array) {
      $numItems = count($array);
      $i = 0;
  foreach($array as $idx => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
    echo '"'.$idx.'":{<br>  ';
     walk_array($val);
     $comma ="," ;
    if(++$i === $numItems) {$comma ="";}
    echo "}". $comma ."<br>";
    } else {
             $comma ="," ;
    if(++$i === $numItems) {$comma ="";}
    echo '"'.$idx.'":"'.$val.'",<br>';
    }
  }
}

walk_array($array);
```

the output :

```
"brands":{
"codes":{
"b":"Apple",
"c":"21",
"d":"18",
},
"items":{
"b":"Google",
"c":"22",
"d":"19",
},
"stock":{
"b":"Samsung",
"c":"23",
"d":{
"b":"Samsung",
"c":"23",
"d":"20",
}
}
}
this is what you need ???
```